# I need help proving something about the pseudoinverse?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

I need to prove that for every vector $x ∈ \mathbb{R}^m$, $(AA^+)x$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $\operatorname{Col}(A)$, where $A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A$.

I don't know where to begin on this proof.

Comment: The orthogonal projection of a vector $x$ onto a subspace $W$ is not the same as the *closest* vector to $x$ in $W$?

Comment: Are you sure about your formula? For me, the pseudo-inverse of $A$ is $A^+ := (A^*A)^{-1}A^*$ (because then $A^+A = \text{Id}$) and the orthogonal projection on $\text{Col}(A)$ is $AA^+$. It should work, because you can write uniquely $x = x_0 + Ay$ for $x_0$ in $\text{Col}(A)^\perp = \ker A^*$, so that $x_0$ is orthogonal to $Ay$, and then $AA^+x=Ay$ is in $\text{Col}(A)$, which should be what you are looking for.

Comment: yes, I meant to say + is the projection of x onto Col A

Comment: Did that help? If yes, maybe we can upgrade to an answer. Else, what is blocking you?